# ANDROID: Google Cloud Vision API Permission Denied

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I was trying to run the sample application, found here Sample Github (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-vision/tree/master/android), I created a certificate and created an API key and applied as indicated. But when I upload the picture I'm getting this exception. I do not know where I made a mistake, you activate the billing, however Billing is enabled on my console. I missed something?

```html
failed to make API request because {
            "code": 403,
            "errors": [
                 {
                   "domain": "global",
                   "message": "Project sixth-tribute-131417 (#703189178423) has billing disabled. Please enable it.",
                    "reason": "forbidden"
                  }
                ],
                    "message": "Project sixth-tribute-131417 (#703189178423) has billing disabled. Please enable it.",
                "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
   }
```

Comment: From inspecting your project ID, it seems you've requested to delete your project.  For testing, please cancel this deletion request, re-add a valid billing account, and try to make the API call again.  From there, we should be in a better position to troubleshoot this.  I have not yet had any issues with any `Vision API` calls.  Lastly, which API method is returning this `403`?